# exception during working with external system: java.lang.AssertionError when Gradle Refresh

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

A new version of jar was added and because of that Intellij was unable to resolve some methods. So I performed Gradle refresh but I'm getting this error instead. Can anybody guide me how to fix this.
IntelliJ version - 2019.3
Gradle version - 6.0

The message tab contains this message:

```
Warning:<i><b>root project 'myproject': Unable to resolve additional project configuration.</b>
Details: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':unified-metadata:unified-metadata-processing:compileClasspath'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find hadoop-common-2.5.0-cdh5.3.0.jar (org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.5.0-cdh5.3.0).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.5.0-cdh5.3.0/hadoop-common-2.5.0-cdh5.3.0.jar</i>
```

Stacktrace:

```
exception during working with external system: java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.createModule(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:154)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.configuration.KotlinMPPGradleProjectResolver.createModule(KotlinMPPGradleProjectResolver.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.createModule(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:165)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.configure.KotlinAndroidMPPGradleProjectResolver.createModule(KotlinAndroidMPPGradleProjectResolver.kt:45)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.TracedProjectResolverExtension.createModule(TracedProjectResolverExtension.java:45)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:344)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$200(GradleProjectResolver.java:60)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:725)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:708)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:276)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:60)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:35)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:57)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:35)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:44)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:100)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:146)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:132)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.executeImpl(ExternalSystemUtil.java:540)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.lambda$execute$1(ExternalSystemUtil.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceImpl.java:150)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:647)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:888)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:585)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:531)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:150)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.lambda$run$0(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:221)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:238)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Try updating the IDE version to the latest. Related issue has been fixed there: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228368

Comment: @Andrey I updated to the latest but still it didn't solve the error. Do you have any other suggestions ?

Comment: Can you build project from command line by Gradle?